# How do I check the ID of the user who just logged in with passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I use passport.js of Express Framework to authenticate the login. I want to get the data of user in database after log in. I set up a middleware to check if the user is logged in then adjust res.locals.user, my source like this:
[image]

My problem is that even though I'm logged in correctly, I can't get the data:

[image]

I think my _id variable at line 10 is wrong. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can please provide more code. But believe one possible error is on line 10 and must be:

```
req.session.passport.user.id
```

Sorry that i wrote as an cant write comments atm.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but can you help me increase my reputation. I am prohibited from asking questions until my reputation increases. @Vasilis

Answer (score 0):

try to catch userID using
console.log(req.user)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).